# Dedup rows with insensitive values in snowflake

Tags: sql, duplicates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case-insensitive

I would like to dedup rows with case insensitive values.

```
original table:
| ID | Name           |
| ---| -------------- |
| 1  | Apple          |
| 2  | Banana         |
| 1  | apple          |
```

desired output after deduping (keep the lowercase):

```
| ID | Name           |
| ---| -------------- |      
| 2  | Banana         |
| 1  | apple          |
```

Following statement only works for case sensitive match.

```
create table DELETE2 as select distinct * from DELETE1;
drop table DELETE1;
alter table DELETE2 rename to DELETE1;
```

I tried to use following statement, but it did not work.

```
ALTER SESSION SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE = TRUE;
```

Thank you!
knozawa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `group by lower(x)`:

```sql
select id, max(name) name
from table
group by 1, lower(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `COLLATE` clause.

The following code does not keep value `apple` in lower case per the request, anyway, it elegantly suppresses dups:

```
with t(id, name) as
(
  select *
    from 
  values
     (1, 'Apple')
    ,(2, 'Banana')
    ,(1, 'apple')
)
select
   distinct
   collate(t.name, 'en-ci') as name
  ,t.* exclude (name)
from t;
```

Result:

```
| NAME   |  ID |
----------------
| Apple  |   1 |
| Banana |   2 |
```